# otroslogviewer log4j pattern problems

Tags: log4j, otroslogviewer

i am trying to work with this open source log viewer (otroslogviewer) which is very nice but i cant seem to create the pattern that will work with the log4j pattern that i am using in my software.

my log4j pattern is: 
%p [%t] (%C{1}:%M():%L) %d{dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm:ss,SSS} S:%X{serviceType} N:%X{requestID}- %m%n

there is very little documentation about how to work with otroslogviewer and create the pattern that you want.

maybe someone here has worked with otroslogviewer and can help out.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:
LEVEL [THREAD] (PROP(A):PROP(B)():PROP(C)) TIMESTAMP S:PROP(D) N:PROP(E)- MESSAGE

Comment: Sorry, this doesnt work at all...
the pattern is not even recognized by the application an it doesnt seem to want to add it to the pattern list.
i tried using it with the tester inside the application, same thing, it wont even try to parse the log file.

Comment: Have you changed the dateFormat to `dd/MM/yyy-HH:mm:ss,SSS` within the pattern parser?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but if it can help others: this Pattern works like a charm using "LogMX" log viewer. I've tested it with a log event like:

INFO [thread] (MyClass:method():4513) 26/04/2012-10:25:49,541 S:Service N:ReqID- Test